# Just received a great recommendation letter with one incident of a different student name

Tags: recommendation-letter

In reviewing graduate school applications, I have a letter of recommendation that consists of two paragraphs. The first one is very detailed and personalised. The second one I think is standard and used for all students. The problem is that on the second paragraph, another name is used. I guess the professor copied and pasted it from another letter of recommendation and forgot to correct the name.

How do I ask the professor, politely, to change that name?

Comment: Why do you need the professor to change the name? I would have thought communication from the professor would be sufficient.

Comment: It's good to know that while prospective graduate students often mess up the school name, this problem cuts both ways.

Comment: @MarchHo I'm going to start my own university called [SCHOOL NAME HERE] just to throw everyone off.

Comment: @corsiKa: Is that before or after the University of '); DROP TABLE Schools;-- ?

Comment: You should extend an invitation to the student named in the second paragraph, as evidently the professor considers him also deserving of a letter of recommendation.

Comment: @SteveJessop Sounds like a great place to enroll my nephew, [Little Bobby Tables](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No need to be anything but simple, polite, and direct:

> Dear Professor Careless:
>
> Pardon me, but the second paragraph of your letter has the name of a different student, which I assume to be a mistake.  Would you care to provide a corrected version of your letter?

Comment: (Make sure to replace "Professor Careless" with the actual professor's name when copying and pasting this text.)

Comment: @DanRomik Actually, it would seem fitting not to.

Comment: +1 but I'd be more inclined to write "could you please" or "would you please" rather than "would you care to".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Why? Does it sound rude/confrontational in this context?

Comment: @user121256 I'd rephrase it too, if only because "would you care to" isn't said very often where I live. It does seem slightly confrontational-ish in the same sense that "do you wanna fix the mistake?" would. "Could you please" sounds more polite to me. I don't think it's a big deal though (source: http://www.phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1047).

Comment: "Pardon me" sounds demeaning. It's like saying "with all due respect" when you are thinking ("I hope this idiot in charge understands me").

Comment: I'd simplify and say "the second paragraph of your letter has the name of a different student. Could you provide a corrected version?"  It's just probably just a clerical mistake, not a big issue.

Comment: @AndreasBlass related: [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53198/could-you-please-vs-could-you-kindly), [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156873/could-you-please-repeat-or-could-you-repeat-please) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270542/could-you-please-do-x-vs-could-you-do-x-please/297188#297188).

Comment: Behold, my glorious [bikeshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality).

Comment: Appreciation is magic... Instead of "Pardon me", I suggest starting with "Thank you so very much for the letter of recommendation." and similar wording like, "I noticed the second paragraph of the letter has the name of a different student, which I assume to be an accidental editing error. Could you please provide me a corrected version of the letter?"  and closing with another "thank you" type of sentence, again expressing your appreciation.

Comment: and perhaps add "and is likely to cause confusion when other people read the application" after "an accidental editing error", to make it clear that you're not just being pedantic for your own sake.

Comment: Or, you know, take the *idea* expressed here and write it in whatever words work for your own personal dialect and notions of politeness ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop It may be more polite to say: "If inclined, one may take the idea expressed here and write it in whatever words work for your own personal dialect and notions of politeness". It may also be more professional to remove the smiley.

Comment: @jakebeal You say this, and yet still it continues...

Comment: [Relevant phd comic](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1047)